# Laravel: getting HTTP 404 on existing route

Tags: php, laravel

i'm having an issue with laravel routing, i'm getting 404 HTTP errors when i try to access a specific route.

This is my routing config:

```
/** Api First Version Routes */
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function(){

        // Auth Routes
        Route::post('register', 'Api\AuthController@register')->name('register');
        Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->name('login');
});
```

My route seems to be accessible on `artisan route list` command output

[image: My Route is listed on artisan route:list command]

but when i try to access through my SPA HTTP Client, it returns a not found http error, image below.

[image: url not found on browser]

and this error just happens when i try to access the login route.

EDIT*** 
When i remove the route from the prefix group, it works fine, seems that the problem is just when i'm using routing prefix.

Comment: Are you sure you're hosting it at port 80? Which software do you use to host the system?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure, i'm using Apache and all routes works, including my resources routes, is just Login route which is not working.

Comment: Also, when remove my route from the Route::prefix('api') method, it works fine.

Comment: @avenar i'm running apache on port 80, i'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many hours trying i have solved this problem, i tried to remember what modifications i did in my code before getting errors, so i remembered that i removed the code `Passport::routes();` from my `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php` file.

After adding it back to my `AuthServiceProvider.php` file all stuff worked again.